# validateDateTimeRange tag for Oracle MAF

Tags: java, oracle-maf

I'm trying to implement `FROM` and `TO Date` validation in Oracle MAF form.

In ADF I have seen the tag some thing like `<af:validateDateTimeRange minimum="" maximum=""/>`. [From this blog you can get more details](http://adfpractice-fedor.blogspot.in/2013/11/validating-dates-with.html), It can be implemented in ADF application.

But I could't find such tag in Oracle MAF. Can you please suggest me, if you got any link to support this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Frank, below is the workaround to achieve this.

**AMX Page:**

```
<amx:inputDate value="#{bindings.inspFromDate.inputValue}" label="From Date" showRequired="true" inputType="datetime" valueChangeListener="#{validationBean.dateValidation}"/>
<amx:inputDate value="#{bindings.inspToDate.inputValue}" label="To Date" showRequired="true" inputType="datetime" valueChangeListener="#{validationBean.dateValidation}"/>
```

**ValidationBean.java**

```
public void dateValidation(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) throws ParseException {
    String fromDate = (String) AdfmfJavaUtilities.evaluateELExpression("#{bindings.inspFromDate.inputValue}");
    String toDate = (String) AdfmfJavaUtilities.evaluateELExpression("#{bindings.inspToDate.inputValue}");
    
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));

    if (fromDate != null && !fromDate.isEmpty() && toDate != null && !toDate.isEmpty()) {
        
        java.util.Date inputFromDate = formatter.parse(fromDate);
        java.sql.Timestamp formattedFromDate = new Timestamp(inputFromDate.getTime());
        
        java.util.Date inputToDate = formatter.parse(toDate);
        java.sql.Timestamp formattedToDate = new Timestamp(inputToDate.getTime());
        
        if (formattedFromDate.compareTo(formattedToDate) > 0) {
            System.out.println("fromDate is greater than toDate");
            throw new AdfException("From Date should be less than To Date.!", AdfException.INFO);
        } else if (formattedFromDate.compareTo(formattedToDate) < 0) {
            System.out.println("fromDate is less than toDate");
        } else if (formattedFromDate.compareTo(formattedToDate) == 0) {
            System.out.println("fromDate is equal to toDate");             
        }
    }
}
```

This method will get both from date and to date from the front screen and convert into timestamp format to validate which is greater.

If `From Date` is *greater than* `To Date`, then it will show you the alert by saying that *"From Date should be less than To Date.!"*. Below is the screenshot, how it will render in the front screen.

[image]

Hope this helps some one.!

Answer (score 1):

you would need to use a value change listener. There is no equivalent tag in MAF

Frank